# List of elements of list that obey certain codition in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists of variables L1, a single list of variables L2, and a list of lists of variables L3 in which the elements are the sublists of L1 that share a variable with L2.

I have a predicate common_v(L1,L2,L3) that returns the elements of L3, but only one at a time.

It works like this:

```
?- L1= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]],
   L2= [C,X,Z],
   common_v([[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]],[C,X,Z],L3).

L1= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]], L2= [C,X,Z], L3= [A,B,C];
L1= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]], L2= [C,X,Z], L3= [D,C,A];
false.
```

But it should work like this:

```
L1= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]],
L2= [C,X,Z],
common_v([[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]],[C,X,Z],L3).
```

```
L1= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]], L2= [C,X,Z], L3= [[A,B,C],[D,C,A]].
```

How could I implement it? The predicate common_v is defined as follows:

```
common_v(L1,L2,L3):- member(L,L1),member(E,L2),member(F,L),E==F.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your predicate exactly fulfills the specification "...but only one at a time." as that probably means "generative successive solutions on backtracking".

You additionally want to have the solutions collected in a bag.

However, your fix has to fix your predicate to. Because `L3` in there is not right.

```
common_v(L1,L2,L):- member(L,L1),member(E,L2),member(F,L),E==F.
```

Then:

```
common_v(L1,L2,L):- member(L,L1),member(E,L2),member(F,L),E==F.

:- begin_tests(bagit).

test(one) :-
  L1 = [[A,B,C],[D,C,A],[B,F,E],[G,H,I]],
  L2 = [C,X,Z],
  bagof(Lx,common_v(L1,L2,Lx),S),
  S == [[A,B,C],[D,C,A]].

:- end_tests(bagit).

rt :- run_tests(bagit).
```

Query:

```
?- rt.
% PL-Unit: bagit . done
% test passed
true.
```